# Creating a component based on Canvas in WindowsPhone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to create a draggable component using multiple Canvas elements, it will be used multiple times in the same panel. How to accomplish it in WindowsPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate user control containing many Canvas elements and use this Custom Control many times in the same Panel.

http://www.microsoft.com/expression/resources/BlendTraining/Day.aspx?day=3#Create